# problema sincronismo volley

Tags: volley

Quiero comprobar en una base de datos si existe o no un usuario pero al hacer la llamada no me funciona, siempre devuelve el valor true, lo estoy haciendo con la libreria Volley, y me ejecuta antes el return que el void onResponse. como se podria hacer para que espere a que se ejecute el onResponse?

```
 public boolean encontrarUsuario(String nombre){
        seguir=true;
        Response.Listener<String> respoListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    String texto =jsonResponse.getString("respuesta");
                    if (texto.equals("verdadero"))
                        seguir=true;
                    else
                        seguir=false;
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        ComprobarUsuario datosUsuario=new ComprobarUsuario(respoListener, nombre);
        RequestQueue queque = Volley.newRequestQueue(contexto);
        queque.add(datosUsuario);
        return seguir;
    }
```

Comment: Asi funciona Volley, es asincrono, hasta que obtienes la respuesta del servidor puedes saber si existe o no el registro

Answer (score 0):

La solución podría ser ejecutar un método al obtener la respuesta del servidor, ya que volley es asíncrono:

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                String texto =jsonResponse.getString("respuesta");
                comprobar(texto)

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


public boolean comprobar(Strin texto){
   if (texto.equals("verdadero")){
         return true;
     }else{
      return false;
  }                       

}
```

Answer (score 0):

La solucion podria ser ejecutar un metodo al obtener la respuesta del servidor, ya que volley es asincono:

```
 public void encontrarUsuario(String nombre){

    Response.Listener<String> respoListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                String texto =jsonResponse.getString("respuesta");
               comprobar(texto);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    ComprobarUsuario datosUsuario=new ComprobarUsuario(respoListener, nombre);
    RequestQueue queque = Volley.newRequestQueue(contexto);
    queque.add(datosUsuario);

}


public boolean comprobar(Strin texto){
   if (texto.equals("verdadero")){
         return true;
     }else{
      return false;
  }                       

}
```

Comment: OK, gracias, esa opción no me vale porque llamo al método desde otra clase y tengo que leer el valor desde esa clase. Tendré que cambiar la clase desde la que lo llamo. No hay llamadas sincronas?